# getuikit modal window not showing

Tags: html, css, getuikit

I have the following html code :

```
<html>
<title> Reddit </title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.20/css/uikit.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.20/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.20/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/core/modal.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button class="md-btn md-btn-success" data-uk-modal="{target:'#my_id'}">Open 
Dialogue</button>

<div class="uk-modal" id="my_id" >  
<div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <div class="uk-modal-header">
        Custom Content here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
<button type="button" class="md-btn md-btn-flat uk-modal-
close">Close</button>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where I load the uikit components through getuikit cdn links. However the modal window is not displayed at all. I dont know if I have included everything correctly. Please help.

Comment: Your 4th <script> line appears superfluous - it is from a different release of uikit and is probably causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues in your code:

1. Firstly, as DaveP has pointed out, you are using UIKit 3, as opposed to the older UIKit 2. You do not need the 4th script line as all the components are integrated into uikit.js
2. As such, refer to the new [Modal documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal). 3 changes are required:

   - For the activator button, instead of using `data-uk-modal="{target:'#my_id'}"`, change it to `uk-toggle="target: #my_id"`
   - Add `uk-modal` to the actual modal div (i.e. `<div class="uk-modal" id="my_id" uk-modal>` )
   - Place your `uk-modal-footer` div within the `uk-modal-dialog` div.
3. Full Code:

   ```
   <html>

   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.20/css/uikit.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.20/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.20/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
       <button class="md-btn md-btn-success" uk-toggle="target: #my_id">Open Dialogue</button>

       <div class="uk-modal" id="my_id" uk-modal>  
           <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
               <div class="uk-modal-header">
                   Custom Content here
               </div>

               <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
                   <button type="button" class="md-btn md-btn-flat uk-modal-close">Close</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   *Sidenote: You are mixing in Bootstrap classes as well, generally its a good idea to stick to just one frontend framework.*